# Treeview - loop all nodes and change text in child node

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I need to do loop over all nodes in my Treeview and then change text of It If my string matches. I found that you must do a recursive loop, but I can't figure how could I use this. Here is recursive looping:

```
  Private Sub PrintRecursive(ByVal n As TreeNode)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(n.Text)
        MessageBox.Show(n.Text)
        Dim aNode As TreeNode
        For Each aNode In n.Nodes
            PrintRecursive(aNode)
        Next
    End Sub

    ' Call the procedure using the top nodes of the treeview.
    Private Sub CallRecursive(ByVal aTreeView As TreeView)
        Dim n As TreeNode
        For Each n In aTreeView.Nodes
            PrintRecursive(n)

        Next
    End Sub
```

For example, if my string is "New folder" I need to loop through Treeview for same Node.text so that I can change It. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the text, you can supply the old and the new text as a parameter like this:

```
Private Sub PrintRecursive(ByVal n As TreeNode, oldText As String, newText As String)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(n.Text)
    MessageBox.Show(n.Text)
    If String.Compare(n.Text, oldText, True) = 0 Then
        n.Text = newText
    End If
    Dim aNode As TreeNode
    For Each aNode In n.Nodes
        PrintRecursive(aNode, oldText, newText)
    Next
End Sub

' Call the procedure using the top nodes of the treeview.
Private Sub CallRecursive(ByVal aTreeView As TreeView, oldText As String, newText As String)
    Dim n As TreeNode
    For Each n In aTreeView.Nodes
        PrintRecursive(n, oldText, newText)
    Next
End Sub
```

This way, each node is checked for the text and the new text is applied if the existing text matches the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that, It works. I also found a solution which does exactly what I need : http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2014/10/12/find-a-treeview-node-programmatically.aspx